# Qt - LNK2019 when using function of a namespace in member function of a class

Tags: c++, qt

I have a namespace with function declarations inside `Project\test\compare_structs.h`:

```
#ifndef COMPARE_STRUCTS_H
#define COMPARE_STRUCTS_H

#include <QtTest/QtTest>
#include "include/Utils/containers.h"

namespace compare_structs {
    void compareRawData(RAW_DATA actual, RAW_DATA expected);
    ...
}

#endif // COMPARE_STRUCTS_H
```

I define the functions inside `Project\test\compare_structs.cpp`:

```
#include "compare_structs.h"

void compare_structs::compareRawData(RAW_DATA actual, RAW_DATA expected)
{
    ...
}
```

I also added the `.h` and `.cpp` files to Qts `.pro` file:

```
test {
HEADERS +=  ...
            test/sql_db_test.h \
            test/compare_structs.h \

SOURCES +=  ...
            test/sql_db_test.cpp \
            test/compare_structs.cpp \
}
```

Now I `#include` the `compare_structs.h` to a class `.h` and call it inside the `.cpp` file:

`Project\test\sql_db_test.h`:

```
#ifndef SQL_DB_TEST_H
#define SQL_DB_TEST_H

...
#include "test/compare_structs.h"

class Sql_DB_Test : public QObject
{
    ...

private slots:
    ...
    void add_get_raw_data_test();
    ...
};

#endif // SQL_DB_TEST_H
```

`Project\main\test\sql_db_test.cpp`:

```
#include "sql_db_test.h"

void Sql_DB_Test::add_get_raw_data_test()
{
    ...
    compare_structs::compareRawData(rawBack, raw); //LNK2019
}
```

The error message:

`sql_db_test.obj:-1: Fehler: LNK2019: Verweis auf nicht aufgelöstes externes Symbol ""void __cdecl compare_structs::compareRawData(struct RAW_DATA,struct RAW_DATA)" (?compareRawData@compare_structs@@YAXURAW_DATA@@0@Z)" in Funktion ""private: void __thiscall Sql_DB_Test::add_get_raw_data_test(void)" (?add_get_raw_data_test@Sql_DB_Test@@AAEXXZ)".`

*free* translation:
`unresolved externel symbol ""void __cdecl compare_structs::compareRawData(struct RAW_DATA,struct RAW_DATA)" (?compareRawData@compare_structs@@YAXURAW_DATA@@0@Z)" in function ""private: void __thiscall Sql_DB_Test::add_get_raw_data_test(void)" (?add_get_raw_data_test@Sql_DB_Test@@AAEXXZ)".`

What causes the linker error ?

Comment: What is the text of the linker error?

Comment: @PhilBrubaker I added it.

Comment: Are your `sql_db_test.*` files also part of (i.e., built via) the `.pro` file?

Comment: @PhilBrubaker Yes, I just skipped them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds exactly like what happens each time I add a new file to a Qt Project. Qt Creator gets confused about the need to rebuild its own makefile.

If a complete "Clean all" followed by "Rebuild all" from the Qt Creator menu doesn't work, then simply go up to the parent folder where your project is located and delete the `build-...` folder that corresponds to your project.

Then "Clean all" and "Rebuild all" again.

Comment: That was insane. I allready *Cleanded* and *Rebuild all* before without success, so after your post just deleted everything in the Build folder and it worked.... Thanks